Seeking recommendations for key research papers on targeted password guessing
I am currently delving into the field of cybersecurity, specifically focusing on the area of targeted password guessing. I'm interested in understanding the most influential and critical research papers that have shaped this field. If anyone could recommend seminal works or important studies that cover the strategies, methodologies, or any novel approaches in targeted password guessing, I would greatly appreciate it. Links to the papers or their citations would also be incredibly helpful.

I recommend you start with the following paper:
Joseph Bonneau.  The Science of Guessing: Analyzing an Anonymized Corpus of 70 Million Passwords.  IEEE Security & Privacy 2012.
Then, to find other good papers on the subject, use standard methods to conduct a literature search (see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/351 and https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/102411/705): namely, read the related work section in that paper to find prior work, and look up that paper in Google Scholar and find papers that cite it.  This will give you lots of candidate papers, and you should filter them down, towards papers that seem to be of high quality (e.g., have many citations, as listed on Google Scholar, adjusted for the year they were published; or were published in a top conference/journal in the field) and of high relevance (based on the abstract).  Repeat recursively with each paper you find until the process converges.
By the way, for the future, generally we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and show us what research you've done in the question.
